# Angular templates and cache invalidation

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a project that uses Angular1, we hit the problem where when we change an html template the users will not see the change until a hard refresh is performed. Ideal would be to have the cache service to check a timestamp and invalidate the cached file. As an example now I edited a template used by the $stateProvider.

My questions is what solutions or best practices are used to solve the problem?

P.S since our JS files are combined in 1 file we fixed the problem there by appending a timestamp in the script tag from our PHP backend

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question! We've had the same issue in a project that uses Angular1.x. We solved it using [**`angular-cache-buster`**](https://github.com/saintmac/angular-cache-buster).

It basically helps you put a [`httpInterceptor`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). All you need is have `ngCacheBuster` in module dependency injection, and inject `httpRequestInterceptorCacheBusterProvider` in the `.config` of your app to set the match list.

For example,

```
httpRequestInterceptorCacheBusterProvider.setMatchlist([/.*api.*/], true);
```

this tells it to cache everything except REST api requests. You can learn more about the configuration [here](https://github.com/saintmac/angular-cache-buster#configure).